# N-dimensional generalization of map and reduce?

Tags: arrays, functional-programming, linear-algebra, mapreduce

Is there any conceptual generalization of higher-order functions like map and reduce but for N-dimensional objects (e.g. arrays or tensors)?

For mapping, I guess it would be a point-wise generalization. In the case of reduction, I have more doubts because the iteration is not trivial. Perhaps it would take an additional argument specifying the dimension (or dimensions?) along which the reduction is applied?

Are such higher-order functions defined in algebra? E.g. do they have a specific name and are studied as such?

Comment: Richard Bird has a series of notes which tackles, for example, reductions over matrices/arrays instead of just lists and provides a host of useful laws (also for the list case). He covers maps, filters, reductions, accumulations and theorems thereof. See his *Lecture notes on functional programming*, I think it was called.

Comment: In multilinear algebra there are kind of analogues of map and reduce, in the form of lifting linear maps to tensor products, or summing (tensor contraction) along compatible dimensions, but they look quite different to what might be intuitive from functional programming, since in multilinear algebra things tend to be basis-independent, so mapping functions like "change every number inside a vector using this function" don't make much sense to do. However, this simple kind of mapping makes a lot of sense in numerics...

Comment: ... so these kind of "apply to every number" or "sum across a dimension" appear in software like MATLAB or NumPy. For example, you can give numpy a multidimensional array, and tell it to take the product along only one dimension, which "collapses" that dimension down.